# Placeholder for all phone OS upgrade questions?

Tags: discussion, repository

The Gingerbread SDK is rumored to get released on November 11. Shortly thereafter I expect there will be a flood of questions "when will {phone X} get Android 2.3?" We're still getting questions like that for Froyo.

My idea is to have one Community Wiki question: "When will my phone get Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)?" that will contain as many models and dates as we can find. Many of us read a lot of Android blogs; whenever a new date is announced (even if it's a rumor) we can edit the question to have that information, with links to sources. (Alternatively, we could have answers for each phone model, but I think that would get unwieldy.) That way, we can then close every other question about an individual phone and point it to the CW question.

And, of course, being Community Wiki will allow more people to be able to edit it.

Thoughts?

Update: It would probably be worthwhile to have a Froyo question too. There are still devices out there waiting for that upgrade.

Comment: Great work you guys

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-3-gingerbread

Comment: I also did one for Froyo, since there are still a number of outliers. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, excellent idea. It's great way to curb the redundant questions and it's a good sticky post that will likely get some link backs from other sites.

Also, I agree, the answers should be updated in the question.  It will get very unwieldy having a separate answer for each phone.

**Maybe something like this:**

***Title:*** 
When will my phone get Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)?

***Body:*** 
Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) was released on November 11th, 2010.  This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates for devices. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the Manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded.

If you don't have enough rep to edit the wiki, leave your suggestion in a comment or answer and someone will update the list.

### Phones

---

**HTC G1**

- OTA: Never ([confirmed](http://htc.com))
- Unofficial: ?

**Motorola Droid**

- OTA: Never [(rumored)](http://www.mobiclue.com/android-3-0-gingerbread-features-supported-phones.html)
- Unofficial: ?

**Motorola Droid X**

- OTA: 2/30/11 ([confirmed](http://motorola.com))
- Unofficial: download available at [XDA forums now](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

### Tablets

---

Enter Tablets Here...

### Ohter Devices

---

Enter other devices here...

Comment: I like your suggestions. I will make it so.

Comment: Have added Galaxy S to the main 2.2 thread, but I've got to admit I'm unclear what "Unoffical" means. Is this where we list an "unofficial" ie rumoured date, or is it where we list when unofficial 2.2 OS (eg Cyanogen) was first released for that hardware?

Comment: @GAThrawn, It's the latter.  "Unofficial" would be for the phones that will get no official update to for that Android release but someone has hacked together an update and it's available for download.

Answer (score 2):

How about the question part is purely a "question" (i.e. what is the release dates for all phones?) and the answer is all phones combined in one post. this way we can accept an answer, and the question will be removed from unanswered list.

And more importantly it makes more sense because the website is supposed to be a Question and Answer website :)

Comment: Seems not unreasonable. I'll work on it.

Comment: Agreed. This is the cleanest way to go about it. It fits the Q&A also.